# django save a form for a user that has not registered yet

Tags: django, forms, registration

I need some advice / ideas if someone is inclined to help: I have a javascript interface for manipulating pictures. Basically it's about moving photos around. Once it's done the position of images is saved into a Django form and then saved to database with the owner saved as the current user. Now the trick is that I would like to be able to allow non registered users to play with this interface and then if they like the result they hit save and are redirected to an account registration page and only then the form is actually saved with their user as the owner.

What comes to my mind now is to keep the values of the form in session but I don't know what will happen to the session once the anonymous user registers and becomes another user. I was also thinking of using a 'next' parameter in the registration process with the url filled with get parameters that would be the content of the form but then I don't know if userena is ready to allow that.
Any light on this is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the object without the user and store a reference of that object in the session (or (signed) cookie). If if the user registers, update all the objects with the newly created user.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I pass the object to the session and assign it the new user as the owner.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we did similar thing on our site.
When unregistered user attach photos we save objects to database and assign unique hash which was generated when user came to the page with form. When user hit submit we pass this hash in url and on the next step, when user wants to register, we just get objects from database by this hash and assign user_id to them.

Also we have a cron job which do clean up and removes all lost objects

P.S. Sorry for my english i hope you'll get my point

Comment: Thanks, no worry about your English, I perfectly understand your point, good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to store the data in the browser (html5 localstorage and fallbacks, or similar) and only insert it into the database once the user has signed up. You would need to make sure both things happen inside the same browser 'instance', but things would be easier in the server side.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. But actually I'm not that much into front end and I'd rather do it server side. I definitely need to learn html5 :)